# Do plugin files have to follow a specific convention to be "picked up" by WordPress?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I developed a plugin using the normal convention of naming the main plugin file after the plugin folder (i.e. `prefix-someplugin` for the folder and `prefix-someplugin.php` for the file). However, I saw some plugins that use the following structure:

```
prefix-someplugin
 - plugin-loader.php // This file just loads src/prefix-someplugin.php
 - /src
    - prefix-someplugin.php
```

Obviously, if they used such structure, it means that it works. The issue is that I'm not sure **how** it works, hence my question. How does WP know which file to load as the main plugin file? I would have assumed that it looked for a file named after a folder, just adding `.php` as an extension, but it seems I was wrong.

Does WPjust scan `wp-content/plugins` for folders, and loads all the files it finds in them, or does it follow a different logic?

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

WordPress detects a file as *plugin* when there is a plugin header. So you can store multiple plugins in one directory, and they all will be recognized as different plugins.

Each file with at least `/* Plugin Name: something */` is a plugin.

The reason is that WordPress scans all PHP files in the main directory of a plugin.

You can use any name for the plugin file. Avoid non-plugin files in the main directory. They just eat runtime. Put all other PHP files into sub-directories.

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/File_Header#Plugin_File_Header_Example

Comment: A-ha! Now I get it. I checked the plugin loader file and it contains the plugin header, which is normally in the main plugin file. It seems that the author simply split the file in two (one with just header + loader and one with plugin code), so that all the plugin stuff is in `src` and the tests in `test`. Thanks for the answer. :)