# Can the uniqueness of the plugin file/plugin slug and version number be trusted?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I am wanting to identify plugins and their contents, and am looking to see if I can avoid calculating the hash of all files in each plugin.

My immediate approach was to use the plugin slug or plugin file (see https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/290402/9702 for the distinction) and the version number.

However in the past I have come across plugins where the free version in the WordPress.org plugin repository and the paid-for version have shared the plugin slug and/or plugin file plus had overlapping version numbers. This is bad if you want to know which plugin is installed, because `Foo v2.3` is no longer unique. Unfortunately I have forgotten which plugins did this.

Recently all examples I've seen of free/paid-for plugins have `-pro` appended to the plugin slug for the paid for version. Are there any you know of where the slug/plugin file is still reused for variants of the same plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Not really. There's no *100%* reliable way to guarantee that `wordpress-seo/wp-seo.php` on one site is the same plugin as `wordpress-seo/wp-seo.php` on another site, short of hashing the files, as you mentioned.

It is *highly unlikely* that they are different plugins, but since there is no centralised system for registering unique plugin names, it cannot be guaranteed with 100% certainty.

Plugins on the wordpress.org repository obviously have unique names, but there's no stopping a developer using the same slug for a plugin distributed elsewhere. This can actually [cause problems](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/please-contact-us/), as WordPress may report an update available for an external plugin if there is a plugin with the same name in the wordpress.org repository with a higher version number.